# вывод чисел от 1 до 100 без использования чисел в коде

Tags: java

Всем привет....недавно начал изучать java, и попался мне на ютубе ролик, где один индус
показывал задание на собеседовании.
вывод чисел от 1 до 100 без использования чисел в коде.

вопрос к более опытным камрадам - реально такое на собесе встретить???

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int one = 'A' / 'A'; //1
    String s = ".........."; //10
    for (int i = one; i <= s.length() * s.length(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: почему бы и нет..

Comment: Иногда и на проде такое попадается ;)

Comment: Лично мое мнение, в адекватной компании такую отрезанную от жизни вещь спрашивать точно не станут. Примечание: вопрос скорее относится к разделу "Мета" на SO, т.к. не предполагает наличия "правильного ответа".

Comment: а может кто свой вариант решения предложит?

Comment: @стасевич шестнадцатеричные/восьмиричные/двоичные представления чисел тоже нельзя использовать? Если нет, то вы можете написать что-то в духе: `int one = 'B' - 'A';`, `int two = 'C' - 'A';`, ...

Comment: @StateItPrimitive .... а вот эти вот знания вообще пригодятся, или их можно даже не пытаться запомнить? .... я до сих пор не могу понять зачем и для чего побитовые флаги, как и где мне это пригодтся.

Comment: @стасевич в реальной жизни, если вы идете на интервью в компанию, занимающуюся веб разработкой, то очень навряд ли такое пригодится. Более того, такое явно нерекомендуется использовать в реальном коде, т.к. это не соответствует принципам чистого кода.

Comment: @стасевич, видимо я что-то упускаю, что вы имеете в виду под битовыми флагами? Битовые операции?

Comment: @StateItPrimitive да, все эти сдвиги >>, >>>, xor , ^ и тд и тп.

Comment: @стасевич битовые операции с некоторой вероятностью могут пригодиться, если на работе придется писать оптимизированные библиотеки (+ иногда по мелочи оптимизировать), но в случае java это скорее исключение из правил.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive ясно.... благодарю.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive попал сюда из очереди проверок. *"вопрос скорее относится к разделу "Мета" на SO, т.к. не предполагает наличия "правильного ответа""* - это утверждение не верно. Вопрос относится к Мете, если он о работе сайта SO.

Comment: @Kromster, пожалуй, вы правы, т.к. если посмотреть на описание [meta](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), то это место, обсуждают технические и организационные аспекты работы сайта Stack Overflow. Я погорячился :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (char i = '!'; i < '\u0085'; i++) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]